# Shortcode Attribute contains clone of all shortcode attributes

Tags: shortcode, customization

This is easily the strangest thing I have see wordpress perform.

I have a shortcode, we'll call it `my_foo` . We'll say it has several attributes, `bar_one`, `bar_two`, `bar_three` . This shortcode is part of a plugin which has the sole purpose of adding this shortcode to the operational environment for dashboard users (authors, etc.. )

Understanding the intent above, the composure of `foo` is such :

```
// in plugin file
public function Foo ($atts, $content =null)
{
  $foo_atts = shortcode_atts(
  array(
   'bar_one' => 'F',
   'bar_two' => 'O',
   'bar_three' => 'O',
), $atts, 'my_foo');

return $foo_atts['bar_one'];

}

add_shortcode('my_foo', 'Foo');
```

Now, using the shortcode :

```
[my_foo bar_one='Something other than F']
```

You would expect the result to be : 'Something other than F'

instead, I receive "Array".

Let's look at what is actually in `bar_one` ...

Modify it to print_r this array :

```
public function Foo ($atts, $content =null)
{
  $foo_atts = shortcode_atts(
  array(
   'bar_one' => 'F',
   'bar_two' => 'O',
   'bar_three' => 'O',
), $atts, 'my_foo');

print_r($foo_atts['bar_one']);
return $foo_atts['bar_one'];

}

add_shortcode('my_foo', 'Foo');
```

The result is now `Array ( [bar_one] => 'Something other than F')`

If I then take that information and say :

`... print $foo_atts['bar_one']['bar_one']`

I receive `Something other than F` (as a string).

The above second dimension can access the defaults ('O' and 'O' for `bar_two` and `bar_three`) respectively.

I have never seen this occur before. Any thoughts?

Comment: Not sure I understand the problem here or what you're seeing exactly, but I would expect `print_r($foo_atts['bar_one']);` to be 'Something other than F'. Are you using the `shortcode_atts_my_foo` filter anywhere? Do you get this on a vanilla install?

Comment: No I am not - however I suspect that perhaps another plugin is using that filter incorrectly. I have encountered similar issues with the `the_content` filter and in the past ran the appended list through a "removal" function I wrote. It felt like a bad practice so I wasn't sure if there is a better way to temporary "set" a filter's stack to the WP default without having to iterate through the current list and filter for default actions ?